# StatelessKieSession does not return inserted objects

Tags: java, drools, kie

I want to do some validation using this Drools rule:

```
rule "Test"
    when
        MyRequest(paymentTerm == PaymentTerm.MONTH);
    then
        Validation val = new Validation();
        val.setIsValid(true);
        val.setDescription("It's a monthly term!");
        insert(val);
end
```

I first created a Statefull KieSession, which works as expected, the first time. However, when I rerun the rule, the validation facts are still in Memory, which is not what I want. So, I tried to adjust the example to a Stateless KieSession.

Using `KieSession kSession`:

```
    kSession.insert(req);
    kSession.fireAllRules();
    Collection<?> validations = kSession.getObjects(new ClassObjectFilter(Validation.class));
```

Using `StatelessKieSession kSession`:

```
    List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList<>();
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newInsert(req, "request"));
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newGetObjects(new ClassObjectFilter(Validation.class), "validations"));
    ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));
    Collection<?> validations = (Collection<?>) results.getValue("validations");
```

The statefull session returns a `Validation` object in the `validations` collection and the stateless KieSession returns an empty collection. Why???

KIE / Drools: 6.5.0.Final

Java EE 7, using CDI on WildFly 10.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I need to explicitly specify the order when the fireAllRules command is run. This works:

```
    List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList<>();
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newInsert(req, "request"));
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newFireAllRules());
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newGetObjects(new ClassObjectFilter(Validation.class), "validations"));
    ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));
    Collection<?> validations = (Collection<?>) results.getValue("validations");
```